# Running a Chainlink Node - Can't connect to database

Tags: docker, blockchain, psql

Using docker-desktop on macOS.

I'm trying to run a node following the instructions on [this page](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node).

The database name is `node`, which is the same as the username: `node`. The user has access to the database and can log in using `psql` client.

Connection strings I've tried in the .env file:

```
postgresql://node@localhost/node
postgresql://node:password@localhost/node
postgresql://node:password@localhost:5432/node
postgresql://node:password@127.0.0.1:5432/node
postgresql://node:password@127.0.0.1/node
```

When I run the [start command](https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node#start-the-chainlink-node): `cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink local n` , using docker-desktop on macOS, I get the following stack trace:

```
2020-09-15T14:24:41Z [INFO]  Starting Chainlink Node 0.8.15 at commit a904730bd62c7174b80a2c4ccf885de3e78e3971 cmd/local_client.go:50
2020-09-15T14:24:41Z [INFO]  SGX enclave *NOT* loaded                           cmd/enclave.go:11
2020-09-15T14:24:41Z [INFO]  This version of chainlink was not built with support for SGX tasks cmd/enclave.go:12
2020-09-15T14:24:41Z [INFO]  Locking postgres for exclusive access with 500ms timeout orm/orm.go:69
2020-09-15T14:24:41Z [ERROR] unable to lock ORM: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused logger/default.go:139   stacktrace=github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/core/logger.Error
    /chainlink/core/logger/default.go:117
...
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: You have `docker` in your tags - are you running these apps in different docker containers? If so, the problem is that `localhost` refers to the docker container - you need to link the app container and the database container, then refer to the database container by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with docker networking.

Add `--network host` to the docker run command so that it is:

```
cd ~/.chainlink-kovan && docker run -p 6688:6688 -v ~/.chainlink-kovan:/chainlink -it --env-file=.env smartcontract/chainlink --network host local n
```

This fixes the issue.

Comment: This may fix the issue, but it also opens up the container network to the host. A better solution would be to either expose only the ports you need or to link the application container to the database container. This should **not** be done in production.

Answer (score 3):

The problem probably caused by the fact that your chainlink database has been locked with `Exclusive Lock` and before stopping node that locks never removed.

What you do in this situation (as what works for me) is use PgAdmin Ui or similar way to find all Locks then find the Exclusive Lock that is held on the chainlink database and note down its Process id or ids (if multiple exclusive locks there are on chainlink DB)

Log in to your pg client and run `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<pid>)` or `SELECT pg_cancel_backend(<pid>);` Enter PID of those locks here without quotes and meanwhile keep refreshing on pg admin URL to see if those processes stopped If stopped then rerun your chainlink node.