# Running a Chainlink Node - Connecting local Docker/DB to Docker/Node issue in MacOS/OSX

Tags: docker, blockchain, psql, chainlink

Running the Chainlink Node with local docker/postgres in OSX Catalina is quite cumbersome due to failed ORM connection or any others.

Doc used: https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node

To check if my local db is indeed working ok. I've ran these commands with successful results:

```
psql postgresql://suchain:docker@127.0.0.1:5432/chainlink


psql -h localhost -U suchain -d chainlink
```

**What have been tried so far**

1. Adding `--network host` haven't resolve the connection issue

Error Message: `Incorrect Usage. flag provided but not defined: -network`

Note: Tried with `--network=host` - same result

2. Changing the db_url from 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Error Message: `dial error (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused)`

3. Changing the localhost/127.0.0.1 to docker instance name (like `pg-docker`)

Error Message: `hostname resolving error (lookup pg-docker on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host)`

Which other options can be used?

Much thanks in advance

**What pages have been checked before filing this one:**

- [Running a Chainlink Node - Can't connect to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904185/running-a-chainlink-node-cant-connect-to-database)
- [CHAINLINK NODE: How might I approach fixing "unable to lock ORM" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64380656/chainlink-node-how-might-i-approach-fixing-unable-to-lock-orm-errors)
- https://youtu.be/jJOjyDpg1aA?t=521

Comment: When running a docker node, `localhost` points to the localhost inside the docker environment. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89877/chainlink-node-not-connecting-to-external-adapter Can you try finding you private or local IP? 

Otherwise, it might be easier for you to run the node in develop mode instead of docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Patrick. The root cause is the same as in this [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89877/chainlink-node-not-connecting-to-external-adapter)

Replacing the db link from localhost/127.0.0.1 to the private/local IP(192.168.0.x) fixed the issue.

FYI: in mac os to find your IP is `ifconfig`. You'll need to find the `en0`